# i want to duplicate a line in a file with some change

Tags: linux, sed

For example :
file1 contains :

```
This is an example. 
This is Sed example. 
This is an example.
```

I want to create a file like :

```
This is an example. 
This is Sed example.
This is awk example. 
This is an example.
```

and this should be everywhere in the file it finds the keyword: `sed`, it should change `sed` to `awk` and print the entire line with the change just below the original line in that file itself

thanks

Comment: Tell us what did you try?

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\bsed\b/I{p;s//awk/g}' file
```

This matches the word `sed` in any combination of case, prints the original line and then substitutes the word `awk` throughout the line and prints that line too.

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` version:

```
awk '{IGNORECASE=1} $0 ~ /^.*sed.*$/ { print; gsub("sed", "awk" ); print; next}1' file.txt
```

Output:

```
This is an example. 
This is Sed example.
This is awk example. 
This is an example.
```